# No matching member function error inside lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This is quite a strange error to me. Check the code below:

```C++
void test(void){
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("hello");
    auto fn=[=](){
        v.push_back("world");
    };
}
```

The first **push_back** method passed the compilation but the second failed, yielding the error:

> **Error:no matching member function for call to 'push_back'**

The compiler note is:

> **Note:(687, 36) candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const vector' (aka 'const vector, allocator > >')

But the method is not marked `const**`.
Well I am not using any const argument and I cannot figure what the compiler is trying to tell me. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lambda call operator member functions are `const` by default. If you want a mutable call operator, say `mutable`:

```
auto fn = [=]() mutable {
//              ^^^^^^^
    v.push_back("world");
};
```

Having `const` be the default forces you to be explicit about the fact that you mean to capture a *copy* of the vector and mutate that copy, rather than the original vector `v`.

By contrast, variables that are captured by reference can be mutated by const-qualified member functions:

```
auto fn = [&]() {
//        ^^^
    v.push_back("world");  // modifies original "V"!
};
```

(This is essentially because `const T` is the same as `T` when `T = U &`; there are no "constant references" in C++.)

Comment: Probably want to capture by reference as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not "as well", but rather "instead".

Comment: Ah yes.  Instead indeed

Comment: Well what is it mean that you want to "capture a copy and mutate that copy, rather than the original v"? I tested this using `mutate`, add a line of code that each time i call that lambda function, i print `&v` out, and seems that the address of that two "copies" are the same?

Comment: @Heranort: Compare it with the address of the very first vector `v` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

capture by value is `const` use the keyword `mutable` (doesn't change the original vector):

```
auto fn = [=]() mutable {
    v.push_back("world");
};
```

or by reference (changes the original vector):

```
auto fn = [&]() {
    v.push_back("world");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `C++14` tag and for the sake of completeness, I'd cite also the *initializer list* as an alternative solution:

```
[&vec = v](){ vec.push_back("world") };
```

If you want to capture by copy instead of by reference:

```
[vec = v]() mutable { vec.push_back("world") };
```

Initializer lists as a (let me say) *capture method* are available since `C++14`, as already mentioned.